# What is the best map provider solution for repetitive routing use?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, openstreetmap, routing

**[edit]**

What is the best solution in terms of cost effectiveness, stability & speed for running a lot of routing requests and comparing them. lots of times over and over?
I understand now that it can be a combination of several tools.

*A simple solution is always better...*

**[original]**

I want to take a route I've gotten via a routing service like Google-maps or CloudMade and add several way-points to it. then check how they affect the time and distance of the route. the problem is that i need to do this Many, many times per day. (i have big list of routes and way-points) and this can get expensive. the services are not free..

a) What is the best map / routing provider for such a thing?

b) Alternatively, is it possible to download an entire database of such maps & a routing solution to use it in-house? (only if it's cost effective)

Thanks!

Comment: what regions? I know certain GIS shops have routes that you could download for free.

Comment: Hi @Steve, I need the solution to globally applicable. But if you must, we can focus on Europe, North America and the rest of the developed world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much any solution you find that fits your needs (high usage, cost-effective) is going to based on [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) data. Here are a couple options:

- **[MapQuest Open Directions API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/directions-service)** is based on OSM data and is completely free for any use. See the terms on their page. They allow you to "request a multi-point route for up to 50 locations".
- **[YOURS](http://www.yournavigation.org/)** is also based on OSM data but, unlike the MapQuest service, the code is available so you could run everything in-house if you wanted. They've also got a hosted version at http://www.yournavigation.org that you can use though.

There are many other routing engines based on OSM data. I'd recommend taking a look at these articles:

- [Online routing services based on OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters)
- [Overview of routing on the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing)

Comment: Thanks @Rohan!
I understand that OSM is a must.
What about CloudMade? how does it compare to MapQuest?
yournavigation.org is failing my simple 2 way-points navigation queries :(

Comment: Both CloudMade and MapQuest use proprietary routing engines that are based on the OSM data. I think CloudMade's TOS precludes any commercial use: "(b) Any use by you of any of the CloudMade Materials and CloudMade Site other than for your personal use is strictly prohibited."